# Error:Printer halted. kill() called! SKR 1.3 TFT35 3.0

Tags: marlin, troubleshooting, skr-v1.3

I am trying to fix the very last error on my printer (custom built).

```
Error:Printer halted. kill() called!
```

This error occures about 5-10 minutes into a print (XYZ Cube) and usually after finishing the second layer.
All temperatures are working as far as I can tell: heats up fine (if a little slow) and all sensors are working; 50 °C bed, 190 °C hotend, all axis are moving, homing and stepping fine and I haven't noticed any overheating issues on the steppers themselves. I have the SD card plugged into the screen rather than the mainboard as it had difficulty reading from the mainboard when I first tested it.

After this happens I can no longer move any axis from the interface and have to run a power cycle to get control back.

Parts:

- BTT SKR 1.3 (Marlin 2.0, TMC2209 drivers UART)
- TFT35 3.0 (Latest firmware)
- NC X/Y endstop switches
- Inductive Z Probe (generic blue square one)
- Dual Z steppers
- J-Head v6 hotend

Notes:

I dont have much knowlage of Marlin firmware, so please be descriptive if I am missing something in the firmware (e.g. "edit `//#define DUAL_Z_STEPPERS` in `Marlin/Configuration_adv.h`" to define the use of dual Z steppers by altering the line to `#define DUAL_Z_STEPPERS`)

It's not possible to plug my printer into a computer, it's over 5 m away, my laptop is broken and I haven't set up my Raspberry Pi yet.

I do not know how to set up SD card logging if that is even a posibility.

Comment: A USB extension cable isn't that expensive anymore! My 5 m one saved me a lot of times! :-) This error message is common in case the firmware thinks the hardware is getting into trouble, have you monitored the temperature of the nozzle when it shuts down? E.g. is the part cooling fan kicking in?

Comment: I don't have a part cooling fan, only a hotend fan (need to print a bracket for part cooler) is there Sd card logging?

Comment: [SD card logging](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M928.html) can be done with `M928 log.txt`, to stop logging use `M29`.